# Resharper dotSettings file getting modified every time

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper

I recently upgraded from Resharper 8 to Resharper 9.0 Update 1.

There is a common Resharper dotSettings file checked-in our solution folder.

Problem is every time I open solution, dotSettings file is getting modified. Below is the diff:

Original:

```
<s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/Environment/SettingsMigration/IsMigratorApplied/=JetBrains_002EReSharper_002EPsi_002ECSharp_002ECodeStyle_002ESettingsUpgrade_002EMigrateBlankLinesAroundFieldToBlankLinesAroundProperty/@EntryIndexedValue">True</s:Boolean></wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

Modified:

```
<s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/Environment/SettingsMigration/IsMigratorApplied/=JetBrains_002EReSharper_002EPsi_002ECSharp_002ECodeStyle_002ECSharpFileLayoutPatternsUpgrade/@EntryIndexedValue">True</s:Boolean>
<s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/Environment/SettingsMigration/IsMigratorApplied/=JetBrains_002EReSharper_002EPsi_002ECSharp_002ECodeStyle_002ESettingsUpgrade_002EMigrateBlankLinesAroundFieldToBlankLinesAroundProperty/@EntryIndexedValue">True</s:Boolean>
<s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/Environment/SettingsMigration/IsMigratorApplied/=JetBrains_002EReSharper_002EPsi_002ECSharp_002ECodeStyle_002ESettingsUpgrade_002EMigrateThisQualifierSettings/@EntryIndexedValue">True</s:Boolean></wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

It is bit painful and annoying since I have to undo this change everytime beofe rebasing or checking-in my code.

Is there a way to stop dotSettings file from being modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. You just need to commit these changes. It means that ReSharper has migrated some settings after a version upgrade, and it shouldn't do it again. It's a benign change, once you've accepted the changes and committed, it won't be modified again.